# Appending an object to a list

Tags: python

I have some python code that appends a results object to a list.

```
objs = []
objs.append(results['Contents'])
```

If I print `results['Contents']`, it looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name", "joe"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "name", "jane"
   },
   {
      "id": 3,
      "name", "john"
   }
]
```

However, when I print `objs`, it looks like this - as you can see it is now a list within a list:

```
[
   [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "name", "joe"
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "name", "jane"
      },
      {
         "id": 3,
         "name", "john"
      }
   ]
]
```

This starts to cause me issues as I begin to loop through and append more objects (that are structured just like `results['Contents']`) as follows:

```
objs.append(l_objs['Contents'])
```

As I end up with something like this:

```
[
   [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "name", "joe"
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "name", "jane"
      },
      {
         "id": 3,
         "name", "john"
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "id": 4,
         "name", "pete"
      },
      {
         "id": 5,
         "name", "paul"
      },
      {
         "id": 6,
         "name", "pat"
      }
   ]
]
```

What I'm really looking for is something like this:

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "name", "joe"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "name", "jane"
   },
   {
      "id": 3,
      "name", "john"
   },
   {
      "id": 4,
      "name", "pete"
   },
   {
      "id": 5,
      "name", "paul"
   },
   {
      "id": 6,
      "name", "pat"
   }
]
```

Is it possible to append these result arrays together so that they form one combined object?

I'd expect `len(objs)` to equal 6 in my example as opposed to 2

Comment: Looks like you want `.extend()` rather than `.append()`.

Comment: That works perfect, wasn't aware of ```.extend()```, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `extend` instead of `append`.

```
objs = []
objs.extend(results['Contents'])
```

Comment: [link to a w3 page about `list.extend`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_extend.asp)

Comment: @RoyCohen -[https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

Comment: I don't have an object, I want to do something like this `objs.append({'number': parseInt(aNumber), 'PK': parseInt(aNotherNumber)}`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via the `extend` function, like so:

```py
objs = []
objs.extend(results['Contents']
prints objs
```

Alternatively, you can loop through `results['Contents']`, and use `append`:

```py
objs = []
for item in results['Contents']:
    objs.append(item)
print(objs)
```